# How to update wp bloginfo('admin_email') via php?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am using manageWP and the admin email address for all sites has changed. I know how to view the admin email address, however I can't seem to find anywhere how to update it.

I did find this, however the pages says that it is not intended to be run directly.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option_new_admin_email

Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update_site_option( 'admin_email', 'email@site.com' );
```

This is what did it incase anyone needed it.